# How to select 1 span from 2 in a div using jsoup

Tags: java, html

html code

```
<div title class="Example">
<span>first div</span> <!----> 
<span class="second div">second span</span></div>
```

Java code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("example.com").get();
        Elements elemenx = doc.select("div.Example span");
        for (Element e: elemenx) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
```

How i can get only the first span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, need to add nth-child
    Elements elemenx = doc.select("div.Example span:nth-child(1)");
maybe someone will be useful